# Replace $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f(k,m)$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k,m)$ by $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,n)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> When can we replace
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f(k,m)$ and
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k,m)$ by
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,n)$ ?

For the case $\displaystyle f(k,m)=\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/m}$ since its limit does not exist for it converging to $0$ or $1$, so it won't matter if we replace both $m$ and $k$ by $n$?

Comment: Since this function is continuous (except for where $k=0$ or $m=0$), this should be fine... I think.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: No, it is famously _not_ continuous in the $k\to\infty, m\to\infty$ limit -- taking each of the limits separately you get the indeterminate form $0^0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Damn, multivariable calculus be crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement "since its limit does not exist for it converging to 0 or 1," doesn't make any sense to me, so I'm going to skip over it. Both of the first two limits you've written down *do* exist for this particular function:

\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/m} 
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^0 \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} 1 \\
&= 1
\end{align}

By contrast, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/m} 
&= \lim_{m\to\infty} \left(0\right)^{1/m} \\
&= \lim_{m\to\infty} 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align}

So this is a perfect example of when you cannot swap the order. And if you try the middle case (replacing $m$ and $k$ both with $n$), you'll again get $1$.

In short ... this stuff's subtle, and if there were an easy rule like this, your textbook would probably have mentioned it.

Comment: What if I replace them by n? Only one variable

Comment: If replacing both with $n$ were a legitimate thing to do, you could apply it to either case...but since the two cases get different results, this *proves* that such a replacement isn't OK. In short: no.

Comment: So as long as the original function with two variables converge, I can always replace those two variables by only one variable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the original function converges", so I cannot answer this.

Comment: $f(m,n)$ converges as $m,n\to\infty\Rightarrow f(k,k)$ converges as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: See @Henning's answer above.

Comment: @MFSO_Zhou: If you define ‘$f(m,n)\to a$ as $m,n\to\infty$’ to mean that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(m,n)-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n\ge k$, then yes, this implies that $f(k,k)\to a$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. It's important to note, though, that the reverse implication is in no way true, so this switching to $(k, k)$ is useful only in proving *divergence* or *non*existence of a limit for the $f(m, n)$ case.

Answer (score 2):

When does it work? As a general rule **it doesn't**. In the few cases where it does work, it does so only by accident.

Even for a function as nice, smooth and bounded as $f(k,m)=\tan^{-1}(k-m)$, we get
$$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{k\to\infty} f(k,m) = \pi/2 
\qquad \lim_{k\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} f(k,m) = -\pi/2
\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n,n) = 0 $$

So essentially the only situation in which you can do this replacement is when you *already* know it will work because you have evaluated both limits and seen that they coincide.